# CSS Mobile Menu smooth scroll temporary disabled when parent is fixed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, css-position

On mobile phones if you are on top of a scrollable container - *which resides inside a fixed container*- and by 'mistake' scroll UP instead of DOWN, **the scroll is temporary disabled**.

I think it's a consequence of bouncing effect which occurs when CSS property `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` is added to scrollable containers. The purpose of this CSS property is to enable smooth scroll on mobile browsers.

I posted this question here because I wanted to share my solution to it, so others won't spend time figuring a solution. Unfortunately I haven't found a question which address this issue.

Please take a look at the mobile menu below, and then read the solution posted below.

[image: visual menu description]

[image: html code of menu]

As you can see there are four fixed containers, each containing a scrollable div, in which resides a big list of links inside a `<ul>` parent.

**Important note** The code above contains only HTML structure + its correspondent CSS. The JS was not implied at all, so it's important to understand that this is not a JS issue.

Comment: Please write reasons to downvote. If anything wrong, say it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved by JS. You must add a `scroll` listener to the scrolling container, and check if the scroll becomes 0. If it does become zero, then make it 1. By doing so you completely remove the only case where this issue happens.

```
$('body .vweb-mobile-ul-wrapper .vweb-mobile-ul-parent').scroll(function(){
    if ( $(this).scrollTop() == 0 ) { 
        $(this).scrollTop(1); 
    }
});
```

**Please note** that the same issue also happens when the scrolling container reaches its bottom. If  you wait a few milliseconds, scroll DOWN, and the immediately UP, the scroll is again disabled. Like above the solution is to move the scroll 1px. If the scrollTop value is at the bottom of container, let's say its value is `x`, then you simply make it `$(this).scrollTop(x - 1);`.